# Different accuracy values using the same saved model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, accuracy

I have trained a model in Tensorflow (for some signal classification problem, using mostly convolutional layers, no RNNs), saved It using the callback checkpoints. When I'm testing the said model on a testing dataset I get different accuracy values (very similar but different) at each run. What can be the cause?

All dropout layers are skipped for testing and no shuffle is done on the dataset.

Comment: Can you post your code?